# Dojo style coding

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I'm new to dojo style coding. Got used to pure javascript and then jQuery style. Searched through and got some results such as

- Dojo, when used with closure compiler works best.
- advanced dojo is more OO than procedural type

I'm having problems with

- dojo.require() - whenever I download a plugin for dojo, I get the error - 404 NOT FOUND. and half the time for developing goes in fixing this issue, getting the js file and placing it at location.
- And is it possible to extend the dojo object as in jQuery we extend the root jquery object by using $.fn.somefunction that is internally defined as `jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype`. Is there something similar in dojo.
- And I feel documentation for dojo is not as good as jQuery's.
- What are dijit and dojox ? When I import dojo.js from Google api library, and then using a plugin in dojo, these dijit and dojox were always a problem.

Need some help. I'm porting few plugins from jQuery to dojo. These plugins are not available in dojo.

I feel that you have to use the entire library when coding using dojo, and then compile it to get the optimized code, and export it to whereever needed. Am I right here? if not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think there are three different questions in your post (your third bullet point does not count), and the first one probably cannot be answered without seeing your code. Otherwise, use `dojo.extend()` to extend prototypes, Dijit is the UI library and DojoX is an extension repository. See the [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) dojo.require automatically downloads the needed files through XHR requests. You don't need to download anything manually. If you use the google CDN all classes should download from there, i would recommend to download the full package to your local application and use it from there. Later you probably want to create a [Build](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/build/). You should also read [Starting with Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/hello_dojo/)

2) Enhancing dojo like jQuery don't makes any sense. `dojo` is just the top namespace and under it you have a lot of classes like `dojo.Animation`, `dojo.behavior`, `dojo.Deferred`, `dojo.NodeList` and a lot of other classes. Some are functions like `dojo.connect()` and `dojo.style()`.

If you want to create a new class look into [dojo.declare](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/declare/). You can also create new classes under the `dojo` "namespace" or other namespaces.

If you want to add a new function to the `dojo` namespace, you can just type `dojo.new_function = function(){}` Like normal JavaScript. But i wouldn't recommend that. It can make problems if you upgrade to later Dojo versions.

jQuery and Dojo are completly different. If you type something like `$('.data')` in jQuery  it fetches all dom-nodes with the class "data" and it returns a new object wraped in the `jQuery` class.

In Dojo you use `dojo.query('.data')` for the same effect. But it returns a new object of the type `dojo.NodeList`. If you want to add new functions to the chain ability you need to extend dojo.NodeList.

There already exists some extension like `dojo.NodeList-fx` that adds the Animation effect to the `dojo.NodeList` class. If you load the class with `dojo.require()` your dojo.Nodelist will extend automatically. Look into [Extend dojo.NodeList](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/NodeList.html#id6) for more information.

3) The documentation is quite good, everything you asked is already documented and i provided some ressources you completly find on the main page from Dojo. The difference is that Dojo is a completly Toolkit, including GUI, layout systems, Widgets, data abstraction and a lot of other really high-level stuff. If you never worked with something like that, it could be hard to start with it because it contains so much. jQuery doesn't provide anything like this. So sometimes it is sure easier to start with it.

For documentation look at:

- [Tutorials](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/)
- [Reference Guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/)
- [API Browser](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/)

4) Dojo is a toolkit that uses 3 namespaces in JavaScript `dojo`, `dijit` and `dojox`. The `dojo` namespace contains things that nearly everybody uses later, like a Framework for I18N, L10N, model abstraction like `dojo.data` or `dojo.store` and a lot of other stuff.

Just loading the "dojo.js" file by the way don't give you everything that `dojo` provides.

The `dijit` namespace contains a lot of widgets in Dojo. All Widgets in the `dijit` namespace have full I10N and L10N support. `dijit` contains Dialog, Layout Systems, Widgets like calendar, buttons, select fields, radio fields, a full [WYSIWYG Editor under dijit.Editor](http://jaredj.dojotoolkit.org/editor_dojo15/).

Also see the [Dijit Theme Editor](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.6.0/dojo-release-1.6.0/dijit/themes/themeTester.html) to see what Dijit contains. The complete site including layout is complete based on dijit.

The `dojox` namespace contains a lot of extra functionality that dont fit in `dijit` or are experimental. But not everything is experimental. You find things like the [dojox.grid.DataGrid](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html) or `dojox.charting` ([Start Charting](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/charting/), [Advanced Charting](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/charting_advanced/)) or Systems like [dojox.gfx](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/gfx.html) to create cross-browser graphics that uses SVG, Canvas, VRML, Silverlight or Flash.

Just look into [Beyond Dojo's Core](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/beyond_dojo/) to get a (small) overview what dijit and dojox contains.

Comment: thanks for providing a thoughtful answer.
@Boopathi, Dojo is going to be a lot closer to the style of straight JavaScript so you should be a lot more comfortable with the syntax in those regards. As Sid mentioned, don't think about how you can use Dojo like jQuery. You said yourself based on your research that dojo provides better OO capabilities and so it should encourage you to think like an OO developers. Personally, I don't thinking the promotion of chaining commands one after another is OO, seems pretty procedural to me. Dojo is a big and powerful toolkit, it will take some time.